How can I use the LD_PRELOAD trick on Windows to circumvent MKL performance degradation on AMD CPUs?
How can I use the LD_PRELOAD trick on Windows to circumvent MKL performance degradation on AMD CPUs?
The documentation linked here explains that the LD_PRELOAD trick can be used to force MKL to use the best performing routines by bypassing the CPU check that defaults to inferior routines on non-Intel processors.
How can I achieve this on a Windows system?
PS:
MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5 trick When you have an AMD CPU, can you speed up code that uses the Intel-MKL? cannot work anymore for Intel compiler distribution 2020 and and newer.


Windows does not have an equivalent of LD_PRELOAD. Your best bet is probably using something like detours to hook the function.
